# show loader while fetching initial data in react-redux component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to do initial fetch in component and render Loader while data is fetching. But render() calls before isFetching becomes true and therefore my component is blinking (isFetching=false => isFetching=true => isFetching=false).
I know that i can just render Loader while there is no data and blinking will be gone, but maybe someone knows a more elegant solution?

**actions/files.js**

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';

import { REQUEST_FILES, RECEIVE_FILES } from '../constants'

export function requestFiles() {
  return { type: REQUEST_FILES };
}

export function receiveFiles(files) {
  const payload = files;
  return { payload:payload, type: RECEIVE_FILES };
}

export function getFile(hash) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestFiles());
    fetch('/api/files/'+hash+'/info', {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
        }
        else {
          dispatch(receiveFiles([data]));
        }
      })
      .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });
  }
}
```

**reducers/files.js**

```
import { REQUEST_FILES, RECEIVE_FILES } from '../constants'

var initialState = {
    items: [],
    isFetching: false
}

const files = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_FILES: {
      return { ...state, isFetching:false, items: action.payload };
    }
    case REQUEST_FILES: {
      return { ...state, isFetching:true };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default files;
```

**components/smart/fileboard.jsx**

```
require('styles/app.scss');

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import * as filesActions from '../../actions/files'

import Loader from '../dumb/loader'
import withBoard from './board'
import DumbFileboard from '../dumb/fileboard'


let getFileSrc = require('config').default.getFileSrc;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    files: state.files
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    filesActions: bindActionCreators(filesActions, dispatch)
  }
}


class Fileboard extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.files.items.length === 0) {
      this.props.filesActions.getFile(this.props.params.hash);
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.files.isFetching ? Loader : (
      <DumbFileboard fileSrc={ getFileSrc(this.props.files.items[0]) } />
    );
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withBoard(Fileboard));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the initial state have *isFetching* set to *true*? You can pass an initial state when you create the store with the *createStore* function.

Also, the React docs recommend fetching data in *componentDidMount*:

*if you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.*

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: I cant do so, because there is a case when fetching is not needed (e.g. if data has been loaded in previous page).

Comment: As long the pages share the same store can you derive 'isFetching' from the overall state (ie if the data exists => no need to fetch it and isFetching is false)?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is elegant enough, only three things:

There is no files property in the initial state.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    files: state.files
  }
}
```

Why don't you use the isFetching property from state?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    files: state.files,
    isFetching: state.isFetching
  }
}
```

Then

```
  render() {
    const { isFetching } = this.props;

    return (
      isFetching ? 
        Loader 
        : 
        <DumbFileboard fileSrc={ getFileSrc(this.props.files.items[0]) } />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `Loader` is getting rendered ever (but you're showing a blank child until data is loaded, then child gets data and renders more things).

Instead of this,

```
  render() {
    return this.props.files.isFetching ? Loader : (
      <DumbFileboard fileSrc={ getFileSrc(this.props.files.items[0]) } />
    );
  }
```

you need this:

```
  render() {
    return this.props.files.isFetching ? <Loader/> : (
      <DumbFileboard fileSrc={ getFileSrc(this.props.files.items[0]) } />
    );
  }
```

Note the missing `<` and `/>`.

---

See this fiddle (a simulation of the case):
https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/49bdw76z/

and the fixed one with working Loader: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/u0v8e0zg/